How to pass tstzrange to postgres
Passing tstzrange to postgres in EF Core using
DateTime algus = DateTime.Parse("2024-11-25T00:00:00+02:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime();
DateTime lopp = DateTime.Parse("2025-01-25T22:00:00+02:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime();

await ctx.Database.SqlQuery<DateTime>($@"
select lower(tstzrange '[{algus},{lopp})') as ""Value""
").ToArrayAsync();

throws error
invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "@p0" at character 20
STATEMENT:  select tstzrange '[@p0,@p1)'

How to pass tstzrange to Postgres ?
Code is in ASP.NET 9 MVC controller
Application uses Postgres 12 and later server
and latest Npgsql Entity Framework Core Provider

I don't use Npgsql, but this select tstzrange '[@p0,@p1)' indicates to me a parameter passing issue. Namely I don't see how tstzrange({algus},{lopp},'[)') matches up with Positional and named placeholders from here Basic Usage. Also the query in the error message does not match that in the code, no lower() or as Value.

As PostgreSQL doc, tstzrange is a built-in range type https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN
For Npgsql, range type is mapped to NpgsqlRange<TElement> since no common C# class can hold its value. https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html
The following is an example to parse and select tstzrange:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using NpgsqlTypes;

var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .UseNpgsql("Host=localhost:5433;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=postgres")
    //.EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
    //.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Trace)
    .Options;

var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(options);

DateTime algus = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2024-11-25T00:00:00+02:00").UtcDateTime;
DateTime lopp = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2025-01-25T22:00:00+02:00").UtcDateTime;

var range = new NpgsqlRange<DateTime>(algus, lopp);

var r1 = await ctx.Database.SqlQuery<NpgsqlRange<DateTime>>($"select {range} as \"Value\"").FirstAsync();
var list = await ctx.Database.SqlQuery<NpgsqlRange<DateTime>>($"select {range}").ToListAsync();

Console.WriteLine(r1.LowerBound);
Console.WriteLine(r1.UpperBound);

var r2 = list[0];

Console.WriteLine(r2.LowerBound);
Console.WriteLine(r2.UpperBound);


public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}



Posted related question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79314728/convert-fullcalender-select-event-start-to-c-sharp
