Convert fullcalender select event start datetime to C#
https://fullcalendar.io/ select event saves start time using code from answer How to pass tstzrange to postgres
javascript:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const calOpts = {
  locale: 'ee',
  slotDuration: '00:15:00',
  slotLabelInterval: '00:15',
  allDaySlot: false,
  selectConstraint: 'businessHours',
  select : function( selectionInfo  ) {
     document.getElementById('start').value = selectionInfo.start
     },
    selectable: true,
   events: { url: 'api/fullcalendar' }
   }
  const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar')
  calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, calOpts)
  calendar.render()
  })

html:
<form action="~/kinnitatud" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="start" id="start" />
<input type='submit'/>
</form>

selectionInfo.start contains localized value like

Mon Dec 30 2024 09:30:00 GMT+0200 (Ida-Euroopa standardaeg)

.NET 9 MVC controller parses it using
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Kinnitatud(string start) {
DateTime algus = DateTimeOffset.Parse(start,new CultureInfo("ee")).UtcDateTime;
}

DateTimeOffset.Parse throws exeption:
String 'Mon Dec 30 2024 09:30:00 GMT+0200 (Ida-Euroopa standardaeg)' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Tried also without

locale: 'ee',

setting but start value is still in ee culture. ee is browser culture. Fullcalendar returns selectionInfo.start in browser culture format always.
Tried in controller to use DateTime.Parse:
DateTime algus = DateTime.Parse(start, new CultureInfo("ee")).ToUniversalTime()

Exception is the same.
How to force fullcalendar to return select start time in invariant culture format ?
Or: users have different cultures in browser. How to parse start selectionInfo.start returned by fullcalendar?

Searching for Ida-Euroopa standardaeg leads me to think that that time is Estonian. But the locale: 'et' leads me to think that it should be Ethiopian. What are you expecting?

et is Estonian. Calendar appears in Estonian locale properly. I expect that select event returns date in invariant culture format or as javascript date object,  not depending on locale setting.

Wikipedia lists Estonia as ee and Ethiopia as et : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes. In any case, that information should be explicit in the question

I updated question and changed culture to ee in both server and client code. Exception remains the same. .Net does not parse start string in ee culture format.

@Flydog57 Tried also without
locale: 'ee',
setting but start value is still in ee culture. ee is browser culture. Fullcalendar returns start in browser culture format always.

You said that

Fullcalendar returns selectionInfo.start in browser culture format always

...but that isn't true. Fullcalendar - as per the documentation - returns a JavaScript DateTime object in the selectionInfo.start field. That's an object, with properties. It is not a pre-formatted string.
What's then happening is that, when you use document.getElementById('start').value = selectionInfo.start to write that value into your start hidden field, JS has to turn the date object into a piece of text. And since you didn't specify any other format for the stringified date, it uses the default toString function of the DateTime class. That is what produces the Mon Dec 30 2024 09:30:00 GMT+0200 (Ida-Euroopa standardaeg) kind of string you're seeing. It's nothing to do with fullCalendar at all, it's entirely down to the way you wrote your code.
A far better way to transmit a date, in a more parseable format, and without any localization baggage, is to use the standard ISO8601 format (e.g. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ). And the JavaScript Datetime object has a function which outputs the date in that exact format.
So all you need to do is write
document.getElementById('start').value = selectionInfo.start.toISOString()

instead.
Then your .NET code should be able to parse the date no problem. I can't test it right now, but you might even be able to write
public async Task<IActionResult> Kinnitatud(DateTime start) {

as the method signature, and save yourself the manual call to DateTimeOffset.Parse().
